# Conky transparancy and refresh issue

Tags: 14.04, gnome, compiz, conky, transparency

I recently upgraded from 12.04 tot 14.04, gnome flashback Compiz.
Conky tranparant behaves abnormally now and I can't fix it.

Transparency turned off, conky acts normally.
Transparency turned on, it is as if upon each refresh, the previous layer isn't removed, so they stack onto eachother.

See screenshots:

no transparency:

[image]

transparant:

[image]

normal:

[image]

I've tried all sorts of combinations of the relevant section in .conkyrc but to no avail...

Relevant lines in .conkyrc:

```
## Create own window in instead of using desktop?
#
own_window yes
own_window_transparent yes
#own_window_type normal
own_window_type override
own_window_class conky-semi
#own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
####
## Some distros also require the following 2 lines.
#
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0
```

I've recently noticed it's variable: it always does this right after startup or 'conky' in terminal, but after a while it stops (so conky's normal), but then after a variable time interval, the 'stacking' starts again...

NB the more I look at it, the more I think it could be a window compositing or window manager and NOT a conky issue. Strange, because apart from the conky refresh issue, the system is running flawlessly (so far...)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you, but I would love to know what is the name of this package/tool

Comment: Try with `own_window_type conky` and also uncomment the `own_window_hints` line.

Comment: Tried each separately and combined... no luck... Thanks anyway though

Comment: `own_window yes
own_window_type pannel
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below` . Which is working fine on my Gnome desktop.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Only thing is, conky dissappears when I click 'show desktop', and I use it a lot... so no option so far...

Comment: Try checking out [their bug tracker and reporting it if you don't see a related bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/conky/bugs/)

Comment: try `own_window_type desktop`.

Comment: Jan, no luck searching the bugs; G_P, nope, doesn't work at all

Comment: Still haven't found a solution... Beginning to think it's a Nemo thing, since I use Nemo as the default file manager and desktop manager(?) Anyone any thoughts??

Comment: Where did you get that theme?! I love it and would like to use it.

Comment: It's Vindsl's, from this forum [Re: HOWTO: VinDSL Conky Script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771033). If you pm me, I can send you the entire .conkyrc file if you want.

Comment: You've been farming bitcoins back in 2014? Lucky you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into same problem. Transparency does not work with window_type override. And window_type desktop disappears on show_desktop. I've come up with this config for ubuntu 14.04 with unity and compiz

own_window_type panel
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

Answer (score 0):

For me this works, even though I don't use compiz and 14.04. After applying new values to `.conkyrc` did you restart conky in terminal like this `killall conky`, then `conky`?

> background yes
> update_interval 1
>
> use_xft yes
> override_utf8_locale yes
> xftalpha 0.84
> uppercase no
>
> own_window yes
> own_window_argb_visual yes
> own_window_transparent yes
> own_window_class conky-semi
> own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

Comment: I already have the same background and update_interval parameters. Inserting the 'use_xft...' phrase, changes a lot of things, but not the refresh issue. I always do **killall conky** followed by **conky**

Comment: To bad. Have you looked through the options in `man conky`?!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this setup

```
-- — WINDOW — #
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value=0,
    own_window=true,
    own_window_transparent=true,
    own_window_hints='undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',

-- — BORDER — #
    border_inner_margin = 1,
    border_outer_margin = 1,
    border_width = 1,
```